# How can I create a single discount code that will work for multiple CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent, drupal, cividiscount

I installed and configured CiviDiscount extension. When I created a discount code, I have not selected any events. Then I tried to use that code on adding participant to a event and it returns "Invalid Discount Code". On the same code, I selected one event. Then I tried to apply that code on that event registration and its worked.

I want to create a discount code that can be used for all the event registration. Please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of [CiviDiscount Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount), then you should be able to see an option `--any event--` on the Discount Form - `civicrm/cividiscount/discount/add?reset=1`.

[image]

If you select this option, you should be able to use the discount code on any event present on the site.